# It says I've visited the site even if I haven't (local storage)

Tags: javascript, html, history

Greetings denizens of stackoverflow.  I have a problem.  I am trying to program something in my portfolio where each time I visit one of my projects, "you have visited X" is logged into the console when the user returns.  For proof of concept, I tried this with my project called "train timer."  However, it says, in the console, that I have visited train timer even if I haven't.  This happens even when I clear my all my browsing data/history/whatever.  What's the deal?  Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Portfolio</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <style>

  #content {
    display: none;
  }
  .thumbnail:hover {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color:#E67F18;
  }
</style>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

   </head>




<body onload="showStuff()">


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Dennis Markham</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li class = "active"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<!-- <div class ="container">
<section class ="row">
<div class ="col-md-1">
</div>
<div class="col-md-10"> 
<a href = "https://dennismarkham.github.io/trainTime/"> <img class = "portfolio" src = "images/dummy_image.png" alt ="train simulator"><span class = "caption">Train Timer </span></img></a> 
<a href = "https://dennismarkham.github.io/week-4-game/"><img class = "portfolio" src = "images/dummy_image.png" alt ="crystal collector"></img></a>
<a href = "#"><img class = "portfolio" src = "images/dummy_image.png" alt ="coming soon..."></img></a>
</div>
<div class = "col-md-1">
  </div>
</section>
</div> -->
<div id = "content">


<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-1">
</div>

<h1 style="padding: 5px; display: inline; border-radius:25px;">Solo Endeavors</h1>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4"   onmouseover ="crystal()">
    <div class="thumbnail" id = "crystalCollector">
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/week-4-game/">
        <img style = "height: 250px" src="images/crystal.png" alt="Crystal" style="width:100%"
        data-toggle="tool-tip" title="HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Crystal Collector</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-4"  onmouseover = "train()">
    <div class="thumbnail" id = "trainTimer">
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/trainTime/">
        <img  style = "height: 250px" src="images/train2.png" alt="Train" style="width:100%" data-toggle="tool-tip" title="HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery, Moment.js, JSON, Bootstrap">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Train Timer</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4" onmouseover="boom()">
    <div class="thumbnail" id = "bombDefuser">
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/BombDefuser/">
        <img style = "height: 250px" src="images/bomb.png" alt="Bomb" style="width:100%" data-toggle="tool-tip" title="HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Bomb Defuser</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4"  onmouseover="thunder()">
    <div class="thumbnail" id = "weatherMonitor">
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/AustinWeatherV2/">
        <img  style = "height: 250px" src="images/weather.png" alt="weather" style="width:100%" data-toggle = "tool-tip" title = "HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery, AJAX, Firebase">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Austin Weather Monitor</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4"  onmouseover="shutter()">
    <div class="thumbnail" id = "reactGallery" >
      <a href="https://rphotogallery.herokuapp.com/">
        <img style = "height: 250px" src="images/camera.png" data-toggle="tool-tip" title = "HTML, CSS, React, Bootstrap" alt="camera" style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>React Photo Gallery</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-4" >
    <div class="thumbnail" id = "roulette">
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/Roulette/">
        <img  style = "height: 250px" src="images/wheel.png" alt="roulette wheel" style="width:100%" data-toggle="tool-tip" title = "HTML, CSS, Javascript, Javascript Animation, JQuery, Bootstrap">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Javascript Roulette Wheel <span style = "color:red; font-style:bold;">(WIP)</span></p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-1">
</div>
<h1 style="padding: 5px; display: inline; border-radius:25px;">Works in Progress (Solo)</h1>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>


   <div class="col-md-4" onmouseover="wiping()">
    <div class="thumbnail" id = "whiteboard" >
      <a href="https://dennismarkham.github.io/Angular_Whiteboard/">
        <img style = "height: 250px" src="images/whiteboard.png" alt="whiteboard" style="width:100%" data-toggle = "tool-tip" title = "HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery, Angular.js">
        <div class="caption">
    <p>AngularJS Whiteboard <span style = "color:red; font-style:bold;">(WIP)</span></p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>


<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-1">
</div>
<h1 style="padding: 5px; display: inline; border-radius:25px;">Group Work</h1>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>


   <div class="col-md-4"  onmouseover = "typing()">
    <div class="thumbnail" id = "chatroom">
      <a href="https://cacheualcorner.herokuapp.com/">
        <img src="images/CC.png" alt="Cache-ual Corner (chat room)" style="width:100%" data-toggle= "tool-tip" title = "HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery, SQL, Express, Moment.JS">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Cache-ual Corner</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
  <div class = "col-md-2"></div>
</div>

</div>
<script>

//on click of .thumbnail a local storage variable with the name of this.id is set to true
//first need to set the variables in local storage and make them false...right?


$(".thumbnail").click(function()
{

  console.log("function firing: setting " + this.id + " to true");

  localStorage.setItem(this.id, "true");
//set visited to true
})
//QUESTIONS:
//-Train sound and magic sound
var trainSound = new Audio("train.wav");
  trainSound.volume = 0.1;
  var crystalSound = new Audio("crystal.wav");
  crystalSound.volume = 0.25;
   var shutterSound = new Audio("shutter.wav");
   shutterSound.volume = 0.2;
  var thunderSound = new Audio("thunder.wav");
  thunderSound.volume = 0.15;
  var boomSound = new Audio("boom.mp3");
  boomSound.volume = 0.15;
  var typingSound = new Audio("typing.wav");
  typingSound.volume = 0.15;
  var wipingSound = new Audio("wiping.wav");
  wipingSound.volume = 0.5;

  function showStuff() {
    $("#content").fadeIn("slow");


    var visitedTrain = localStorage.getItem("trainTimer");

    if (visitedTrain === "true")
    {
      console.log("train timer visited");
    }
}


 function train(){
  trainSound.play();
  console.log("Playing train");
 }
 function crystal(){
  crystalSound.play();
  console.log("Playing crystal");
 }
 function shutter(){
 shutterSound.play();
 console.log("Playing shutter");
 }
 function thunder(){
  thunderSound.play();
  console.log("Playing thunder");
 }
 function boom(){
  boomSound.play();
  console.log("Playing boom");
 }
function typing(){
  typingSound.play();
  console.log("playing typing");
}
function wiping(){
  wipingSound.play();
  console.log("playing wiping");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Go to the console and thereafter to Application tab. Clear all site data from there. If it's still logging then check your code.

Comment: And please upload the required code only. No one is going to scroll through the HTML to find your hidden javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out.  I changed "true" to "visited."

```
    $(".thumbnail").click(function()
{

  console.log("function firing: setting " + this.id + " to true");

  localStorage.setItem(this.id, "visited");
//set visited to true
})
```

and

```
 var visitedTrain = localStorage.getItem("trainTimer");

    if (visitedTrain == "visited")
    {
      console.log("train timer visited");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage object stores data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.
you need to forcefully remove the localStorage like

```
    var visitedTrain = localStorage.getItem("trainTimer");

        if (visitedTrain === "true")
        {
          console.log("train timer visited");
          localStorage.removeItem('trainTimer');
        }
```

this code will work fine,

hope this solves your problem

Comment: Okay, but then if I go back to the portfolio site again, without visiting train timer again, won't that no longer log in the console?

Comment: it will log in to your console if you visited the site again, just check your result after applying this, and accept the answer if it solves your problem, thanks

Comment: It's not doing what I wanted, maybe I'll try this again with cookies :/

Comment: what do you actually want's is unclear with your question

Comment: I want it to log in the console after the user visits train timer, until the user clears his browsing data.  Not before, and not after.